# Rows where value in column A occurs > 1 but the corresponding value in column B doesn't

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
SchoolName|SchoolID
--------------------
School A  |x
School B  |x
School C  |y
School D  |z
School D  |z
```

There are actually more columns, including a unique ID. The above is just for brevity.

What I need to do is select *all* columns, where the SchoolID occurs more than once, but only if the corresponding value in the SchoolName column doesn't.

So I'd like get all columns for the rows with School A and School B, but not the School C and School D rows.

The db is MS SQL 2008 R2.

The original question was terribly confused, hopefully I've managed to rephrase it correctly now!

Comment: Can you elaborate why `School D` should not be returned? What is column B in this example?

Comment: And why should School A & B be returned, when there is no corresponding value that occurs more than once?

Comment: Sorry, should've said "the SchoolName column", not "column B".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tab Alleman, I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that. Hopefully the edited question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window version of `COUNT` to count `SchoolID` and `SchoolName` occurences:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID) AS cntSchoolID,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolID, SchoolName) AS cntSchoolName 
   FROM mytable ) t
WHERE t.cntSchoolID > 1 AND t.cntSchoolName = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38b05/1)

Answer (score 0):

So do you want something like this?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM yourTable A
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 NULL col
                FROM yourTable 
                WHERE A.SchoolID = SchoolID
                AND A.SchoolName = SchoolName
                GROUP BY SchoolID,SchoolName
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) CA
```

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of CROSS APPLY, useful! Unfortunately, you correctly solved my incorrectly posed original (later edited) question. ;) But thank you, nice SQL!

Answer (score 0):

I would build a list of all the schoolnames that repeat, and all the schoolids that repeat, and then pull all of the rows where the schoolname or the schoolid match:

```
select
*
from
mytable
where
(schoolname in
(
select schoolname
from
mytable
group by schoolname
having count (*) > 1)
OR
schoolid in 
(
select
schoolid
from
mytable
group by schoolid
having count (*) > 1)
 )
```

Ugly, but I think it gives you your desired result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03ee6/10)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I guess you replied to my original, now edited question? Changing the OR to an AND and the SchoolName count to = 1 instead of >1 does give me the desired set though.